# Tkinter in a virtualenv on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tkinter, virtualenv

This has been asked already but no answer has been supplied for computers running Mac OSX. How can I enable tkinter in a python 2.7 virtualenv on mac?

[TKinter in a Virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884075/tkinter-in-a-virtualenv)

Comment: Have you followed the setup guide here --> [Virtualenv](http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Python/virtualenv.html)

Comment: Does this help: http://blog.openpolis.it/2014/06/15/using-tkinter-inside-a-virtualenv-hack/4287 ?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem - and found a simple solution. Just create your environment using

`virtualenv --system-site-packages YourNewEnv`

to make an existing tkinter install (for example from brew or macports) available to your virtual environment.